# Regular expression in R: gsub pattern

Tags: regex, r

I'm learning R's regular expression and I am having trouble understanding this
 `gsub` example:

```
gsub("([.|()\\^{}+$*?]|\\[|\\])", "\\\\\\1", x)
```

So far I think I get:

- if x is alphanumeric it doesn't match so all nothing modified
- if x contains a `.` or `|` or `(` or `{` or `}` or `+` or `$` or `?` it adds `\\` in front of it

I can't explain:

```
> gsub("([.|()\\^{}+$*?]|\\[|\\])", "\\\\\\1", '10\1')
[1] "10\001"
```

or

```
> gsub("([.|()\\^{}+$*?]|\\[|\\])", "\\\\\\1", '10/1')
[1] "10/1"
```

I am also confused why the replacement `"\\\\\\1"` add only two brackets.

I'm suppose to figure out what this function does and I think it's suppose to escape certain special characters ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entire pattern is wrapped in parentheses which allows back-references. This part:

```
[.|()\\^{}+$*?]
```

... is a "character class" so it matches any one of the characters inside teh square-brackets, and as you say it is changing the way the pattern syntax will interpret what would otherwise be meta-characters within the pattern definition.

The next part is a "pipe" character which is the regex-OR followed by an escaped open-square-bracket, another "OR"-pipe, and then an escaped close-square-bracket. Since both R and regex use backslashes as escapes, you need to double them to get an R+regex-escape in patterns   ... but *not* in replacement strings. The close-square-bracket can only be entered in a character class if it is placed first in the string, sot that entire pattern could have been more compactly formed with:

```
 "[][.|()\\^{}+$*?]"  # without the "|\\[|\\])"
```

In replacement strings the form `"\\n"` refers to whatever matched the n-th parenthetical portion of the 'pattern', in this case '\1' is the second portion of the replacement. The first position is "\" which forms an escape and the second "\" forms the backslash. Now get ready to the even weirder part ... how many characters are in that result?

```
> nchar( gsub("([.|()\\^{}+$*?]|\\[|\\])", "\\\\1", '10\1') )
[1] 3
```

And then of course  none of the items in the match is equal to '\1". Somebody writing whatever tutorial you have before you (which I do not think is the `gsub` help page) has a weird sense of humor. Here are a couple of functions that may be useful if you need to create characters that would otherwise be intercepted by the system `readline` function:

```
> intToUtf8(1)
[1] "\001"
> ?intToUtf8
> 0x0
[1] 0
> intToUtf8(0)
[1] ""
> utf8ToInt("")
integer(0)
```

And do look at `?Quotes` where a lot of useful information can be found (under what I would consider a rather unlikely title)  about how R handles octal, hexadecimal and other numbers and special characters.

Comment: I can't get your alternative `gsub` pattern to work - `gsub("([][.|()\\^{}+$*?])","\\1","[ ]")` errors out.

Comment: Agree. This succeeds: `"[][|(.)\\^{}+$*?]"`. Something to do with the order of the meta-characters inside the square-brackets.  `gsub( "([][|(.)\\^{}+$*?])", "hit", "]") #[1] "hit"`

Comment: Awesome! but can you explain the `"\\\\1"` vs. `"\\\\\\1"` i'm not sure i understand that

Comment: Well, since the 'pattern' did not match anything I'm not sure exactly what to explain.

Comment: @BondedDust as in the difference here: `> gsub("([.|()\\^{}+$*?]|\\[|\\])", "\\\\\\1", '10.1')
[1] "10\\.1"
> gsub("([.|()\\^{}+$*?]|\\[|\\])", "\\\\1", '10.1')
[1] "10\\11"` in my original questions vs. your answer

Comment: That wasn't in the original question. There are two effective components to the replacement (which does succeed since there is _now_ a match): (a) the first 4 backslashes that actually turn into an escape and a backslash character and then (b)the back-reference from the 5th and 6th backslashes and the "1". The item matching the material inside the back-reference referenced by the `"\\1"`is a period. There are actually only 5 characters in the result.

Answer (score 4):

The first regex broken down is this

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      [.|()\^{}+$*?] 
   |  \[
   |  \]
 )                             # (1 end)
```

It captures any what's in the 'class' or '[' or ']'  then it looks like it replaces it with `\\\1` which is an escape plus whatever was in capture 1.

So, basically it just escapes a single occurrence of one of those chars.

The regex could be better written as `([.|()^{}\[\]+$*?])` or within a
string as `"([.|()^{}\\[\\]+$*?])"`

Edit (promoting a comment) -

The regex won't match string 10\1 so there should be no replacement. There must be an interpolation (language) on the print out. Looks like its converting it to octal \001. - Since it cant show binary 1 it shows its octal equivalent.

Comment: I think there's also some (possibly unintended) strangeness with `"10\1"` and it escaping `1` - e.g. `cat("10\1")` just returns `10` - from a quick google I think `\1` or `\001` is a null character.

Comment: @thelatemail  - The regex won't match string `10\1` so there should be no replacement. There must be an interpolation (language) problem on the print out. Looks like its converting it to octal `\001`. - Since it cant show 1 it shows its octal equivalent.

Comment: @BondedDust - I need a table to find that.

Comment: @BondedDust  - Its true, I have no sense of humor.

Comment: @sln _"the regex could be better written as.."_ does not work here but the rest helps!

Comment: There's something odd (or at least not documented in R's regex help page) about how the order of the meta-characters inside the character-class affects the result. See the alternatives in the comments under my answer.